# Download files in zip using ZipArchive

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to download files in zip. How can I do this? I tried, but error occurred.

I have a table name is articles:

```
id  |  volume_id  |  image

5    |            9        |   file1.pdf
6    |            9        |   file2.pdf
```

I want to download file1.pdf and file2.pdf in zip based on volume_id

viewarticles.blade.php is:

```
<a href="{{ route('create-zip',['volume_id'=>$article->volume_id]) }}">Download ZIP</a>
```

web.php is:

```
Route::get('create-zip/{volume_id}', 'foruserview@createzip')->name('create-zip');
```

controller is:

```
use App\article;
use ZipArchive;

public function createzip($volume_id)
    {
      $articles = article::where('volume_id',$volume_id)->get();
       $file= public_path(). "/storage/upload_pic/"; 

               $zipFileName = 'AllDocuments.zip';
               $zip = new ZipArchive;

            if ($zip->open($file . '/' . $zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
                foreach($articles as $article) {
                  $images = $article->image;
        $zip->addFile($file, $images);
    }        
    $zip->close();

            }
            // Set Header
            $headers = array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
            );
            $filetopath=$file.'/'.$zipFileName;
            // Create Download Response
            if(file_exists($filetopath)){
                return response()->download($file,$zipFileName,$headers);
            }
    }
```

After click on download button. Zip file of both images related with volume_id should be download.

But error occurs:

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
ZipArchive::close(): Read error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you `dd($zip)` just before `$zip->close();` do you get a file? Are you sure you have a good path to file>

Comment: Path is showing like this: E:\xampp\htdocs\jiwaji_university\public/storage/upload_pic/

Comment: I tried with this:  $file= public_path('storage' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'upload_pic');

Comment: But again same error